# ¿Como sacar el Dia que busco con la herramienta DateTime en C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, date

Tengo un problema al momento de tratar de obtener un dia en especifico con la propiedad DateTime de C#, ya que solo me trae un numero y siempre es el 1.

Codigo del metodo de la fecha

```
var fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
DateTime moment = new DateTime();
int dia = moment.Day;
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dia), "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta haciendo que el formato de la fecha sea DD/mm/YYYY este podrida ser el problema, o con el debuger prosicionate en `int dia = moment.Day;` a ver que resultado te arroja antes de obtener el int

Comment: Estas sacando el dia de una fecha en nulo...crea la fecha con un valor..fijate lo que haces en esta linea: `DateTime moment = new DateTime();
int dia = moment.Day;`

Comment: es cierto lo que dice @PabloClaus , cuando crees moment agregale una fecha valida 
`DateTime moment = DateTime.Today`

Comment: Si haces `DateTime moment = new DateTime();`,moment contendrá `1/1/0001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es ver el dia de la fecha actual, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(), "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Por que lo que estas haciendo es inicializar una fecha por defecto que es 01/01/0001, po eso siempre te va a mostrar 1

Answer (score 0):

Es innecesaria esta parte del código :

```
DateTime moment = new DateTime();
int dia = moment.Day;
```

simplemente emplea la variable fecha que has creado :

```
DateTime fecha = new DateTime();
fecha = DateTime.Now();
int dia = fecha.Day;
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dia), "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```